# Rotate an overlay image concentrically

Tags: android, image, rotation, imageview, overlay

I am very close to a solution but the last bit is eluding me. I have two images of identical size that I have overlayed in a section of my layout. These images will be scaled to fit the screen depending up on screen size. I have used multiple drawables if that is relevant.

Essentially one image is a circle with an airplane in the middle and the other is a little windsock. I want the windsock to sit in the relative position that the wind is coming from.

I have got the windsock to overlay at the start nicely, I can rotate it BUT it is not rotating concentrically and the scale of the windsock changes slightly when I do the rotation. I can see this because when I return the rotation to zero the windsock graphic is not in the starting position and is slightly larger.

So the question is how do I scale the overlay to be the same as what android does when it creates the initial view?

My XML:

```
        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="0.60"
        android:gravity="center"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:text="@string/runwayDirection"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

         <EditText
            android:id="@+id/rwyDirection"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="3"
            android:text="@string/zero"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@null" />

    <FrameLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/aircraftGraphic"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="@string/windRose"
                android:src="@drawable/aircraftgraphic" />
        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/windpic"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="@string/windRose"
                android:src="@drawable/windsockring"
                />
    </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

The code I am using to rotate:

```
public void rotate_windsock(){

float relativeWind=90;
float rwydir;
float windDirection;

if (rwyDirection.getText().toString().matches("")) rwydir=0;
else rwydir=Float.parseFloat(rwyDirection.getText().toString());

if (windAngle.getText().toString().matches("")) windDirection=0;
else windDirection=Float.parseFloat(windAngle.getText().toString());

if (rwydir>windDirection) relativeWind=360-(rwydir-windDirection);
else relativeWind=(windDirection-rwydir);

Matrix matrix=new Matrix();
windSock.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);   //required
matrix.postRotate((float) relativeWind, aircraftGraphic.getWidth()/2, aircraftGraphic.getWidth()/2);
//matrix.postScale(aircraftGraphic.getWidth(), aircraftGraphic.getWidth());
windSock.setImageMatrix(matrix);

}
```

You can see I am currently trying to get the width of the underlying picture and since it is a square use that as the arguments for `postRotate`. I have tried getting the width of `LinearLayout` and I have tried doing a rotate on the underlying image hoping that it would scale to the same as the overlying image but nothing has worked. It is close but is obviously not right.

Anyone help me out? The only other thing I have thought of is shrinking the images further so they aren't scaled but this will waste space on larger screens?

EDIT:

I have tried changing the rotation code to this:

```
Matrix mat = new Matrix();
Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.windsockring);
mat.postRotate(relativeWind);
Bitmap bMapRotate = Bitmap.createBitmap(bMap, 0, 0,bMap.getWidth(),bMap.getHeight(), mat, true);
windSock.setImageBitmap(bMapRotate);
```

Now that appears to work perfectly the difference between the runway direction and wind direction is a multiple of 90 but otherwise the scaling of the windsock is affected?!?!?! What is up with that!

EDIT #2:
OK For those in the future I now have it working thanks to these links:
[Rotate image without shrinking on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9970852/rotate-image-without-shrinking-on-android)
http://learnandroideasily.blogspot.com.au/2013/07/imageview-animation-in-android.html

The code to do it:

```
RotateAnimation rAnimClockWise = new RotateAnimation(0.0f, relativeWind, 1, 0.5f, 1, 0.5f);
rAnimClockWise.setFillAfter(true);
rAnimClockWise.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());       
rAnimClockWise.setDuration(0);
windSock.startAnimation(rAnimClockWise);
```

I know this is incredibly long in the end but I am sure it will help someone in the future!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the edits I made in the origina question for the answer!